# Why do I get a `weird error' (according to overleaf) when trying to compile my pdf with a logo in the footer?

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, footer

I want to include a logo in the footer (here a graphic of a green box as an example) into my document. However, doing so results in errors which stem from the KOMAoptions command and I dont know how to resolve it.
I'm getting the following error while compiling although the document still manages to compile a pdf:

\let 
l.48 \subsection
                {TEST3}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

\let
l.48 \subsection
{TEST3}
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

In the following I have provided a minimal working example,

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
titlepage,
toc=listof,             % Im Inhaltsverzeichnis Eintrag Literatur und Tabllenliste etc. toc=listof -> ohne Nummerierung im Inhaltsverzeichnis
toc=bibliography,       %toc=bibiliography -> ohne Nummerierung im Inhaltsverzeichnis 
headings=standardclasses,       % Einstellungen für die chapter Darstellung
%headings=big,
chapterprefix=true,            % Entfernt Kapitel x vor jeder Kapitelüberschrift
numbers=noenddot,               % Entfernt Endpunkt der Kapitel im Inhaltsverzeichnis als auch im text
twoside=semi
]{scrreport}        % Chapter immer auf neuer Seite begonnen, text nicht eingerückt anders, ...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Diese Pakete sind
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % für die Verwendung 
%\usepackage{ngerman}           % von Umlauten im tex-file
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Zum Einbinden von Formeln
\usepackage{svg}                % Darstellung von Vektorbildern
\usepackage{lipsum}             % Zum Generieren von Dummytext


% ______________Farbliches Layout (Kopf + Fußzeilen + Chapter/Section etc.)_________________________


\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically

\clearpairofpagestyles

\KOMAoptions{
  onpsevenpage={\cfoot*{\vskip \includesvg[width=0.1\textwidth]{Graphics/Other/green1}}}, %Logo on every page forced by *
  onpsoddpage={\cfoot*{\vskip \includesvg[width=0.15\textwidth]{Graphics/Other/green2}}},  %Logo on every page forced by *
}


%____________________________________________________________________________________________



\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage


\chapter{TEST}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{TEST2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\subsection{TEST3}
\subsubsection{TEST4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX probably wants you to provide some kind of dimension after`\vskip`.

Comment: Off topic: You do not have to use the `\KOMAoptions{...}` stuff for different logos in footer  on even and odd pages. Replace this code by `\cefoot*{...}` for (centred) footer on even pages and `\cofoot*{...}` for (centred) footer on odd pages. Package `inputenc` is only needed with older TeX distributions. Remove package `ngerman`.  If you need German, use option `ngerman` for package `babel`.